# Как временно отключить hosts?

Tags: hosts, linux

Для целей тестирования нужно периодически отключать файл /etc/hosts. Как добиться того, чтобы он оставался на месте, но не работал?

Answer (score 3):

Откройте файл (это для Ubuntu)

```
sudo nano /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

и из строки

> `hosts:          files dns`

уберите слово files

> `hosts:          dns`

После этого действие файла hosts будет отменено.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, просто переименовать файл, добавив 1 символ, например.